# Adding flavouring to fermented cider

Tags: cider, flavor, secondary

I have almost finished the first fermentation of my 2nd cider kit, I took a SG reading yesterday and it comes in around 7% (1.064 > 10.11). While I have no problem with it being strong, this and the fact I made the full 40 pints, has caused the flavour (forest fruits) to be extremely weak.

I was looking for advice on adding some form of fruit flavouring to my drink, wether it be fruit juices or a fruit drink like Robinsons. I did have a look at one Robinsons drink though and it contained Sodium Metabisulphite, which I imagine would cause problems for me later when I plan to bottle and prime with sugar.

I don't mind waiting before bottling after I've added the fruit drink, since I planned to transfer from primary, into a secondary and add lactose to sweeten, I just want a strong, fizzy and fruity cider.

Any advice on flavouring would be great. I'd like to avoid buying 100% fruit concentrate since it's expensive, so cheaper yet still effective ways would be ideal.

Thanks,
Carl.

Answer (score 2):

## Artificial drinks - no

Most of them contains preservatives that will kill your fermentation. And if fermentation will not be killed, sugar and water will imbalance original design of your recipe.

## Juices - no

Juices are usually around 1.04 as far as I know, and you went with 1.06, so this will restart your fermentation and dilute the effect.

## Condensed juices / juice concentrate - no

This will probably restart fermentation, or kill yeast (forget about carbonation). Basically, that's what you got in cider kit, so diluting with water to the same OG your cider have will create more of cider, but not more taste.

## Natural / artificial extracts - yes / maybe

There are things like *Natural Organic Apple Extract*. Basically apple juice sans water and sugar. Exactly what your cider seems to be lacking. Or you can forget natural and organic, and buy something like *Apple Flavor Drops*. Most of artificial flavorings doesn't need any preservatives in them, but always read their labels.